# JQuery table sorter doesn't work with date range string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter, string-comparison

I have a column in my table that shows variations of the following text, where the dates vary

```
Requested Statement 7/1/2014 - 9/16/2014
```

tablesorter has trouble sorting this properly, as you can see in this fiddle. The first column will sort when clicked, but the second will not. I also included a table of some string comparisons to show that javascript properly recognizes the order they should be in.

http://jsfiddle.net/kfu4ragh/1/

I tried adding a custom `textExtraction` function but I'm still getting the same results.

It seems that tablesorter is doing something different than a simple `>` or `<` to determine the order of the string values. Is there a way I can alter tablesorter to sort this column correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the second column ("Requested Statement...") is being detected as a date column and the parser is trying to turn that entire string into a date; which is invalid.

Here is [a demo with the relevant extracted out functions from tablesorter](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ved7hhqy/). The result is:

```
// start with "Requested Statement 7/1/2014 - 9/16/2014"
"Requested Statement 2014/7/1 / 9/16/2014" => 0
```

So you'll need to use the `textExtraction` function to target the date ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1106/)):

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    textExtraction : function(node){
        var txt = $(node).text();
        if (/request/i.test(txt)) {
            // return the 3rd block (first date in range)
            txt = txt.split(' ')[2];
        }
        return txt;
    }
});
```

Note that the second date in the string is completely ignored. If you would like to make the second date matter, try this code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1107/)):

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    textExtraction : function(node){
        var d1, d2,
            txt = $(node).text();
        if (/request/i.test(txt)) {
            // return the 3rd block (first date in range)
            txt = txt.split(' ');
            d1 = $.tablesorter.formatFloat(new Date(txt[2]).getTime());
            d2 = $.tablesorter.formatFloat(new Date(txt[4]).getTime());
            // add the times together - there is likely a better
            // method but this works in this situation
            txt = d1 + d2;
        }
        return txt;
    }
});
```